# How to debug eclipse c projects from windows command line?

Tags: c, eclipse

Is there a way to debug the eclipse c project(.c file) from the command line?

Comment: Once eclipse have compiled your C file, it is not an "eclipse project" anymore and you can debug it with whatever debugger you want (which is supporting the debug info compiled into the executable..)

Comment: Also, the .c file itself is not an Eclipse project.  There are command-line tools for Windows that can build executables from C source files, debug them, etc..